# Go golang/groupcache SetNX() equivalent

Tags: go, caching

Im considering using groupcache in a production environment having multiple instances running. Neither the original version nor the modified version of mailgun provides a method that is equivalent to redis SetNX (Only set the K-V if it’s not present).

How would you implement such a method? If you would not, do you have any alternatives in mind?